# CORS error while loading files from the same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

I'm working on website http://www.fsvelicka.cz. I need to load a content of an HTML file to an element. I have an element  and I'm loading the content with $('.about-us-first-col').load("about_us/desc/" + lang + "/first_col.html"); The problem is I'm getting an error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.fsvelicka.cz/first_col' (redirected from 'http://www.fsvelicka.cz/first_col.html') from origin 'http://www.fsvelicka.cz' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The element is inside index.html file and the file I want to load is located in about_us/desc/cz/. I don't understand why I'm getting this error while the file is in the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS cares about the **origin** of which the domain is only one part.

To be on the same origin each of:

- The scheme
- The full hostname
- The port number

… must match.

Your URLs have different schemes. One is `https`, the other is `http`. They are not the same origin.

Generally speaking, you want to be using HTTPS wherever possible. Redirect all requests from your plain HTTP service to HTTPS. That way the HTML page will be served over HTTPS and the origins will match.